# How do you convert a dataframe to a great_expectations dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, great-expectations

I have a pandas or pyspark dataframe `df` where I want to run an expectation against.
I already have my dataframe in memory. How can I convert my dataframe to a great_expectations dataset?

so that i can do for example:

```
df.expect_column_to_exist("my_column")
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what is your problem and how you solved it ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import great_expectations as ge
```

for pandas:

```
df_ge = ge.from_pandas(df)
```

or

```
df_ge = ge.dataset.PandasDataset(df)
```

for pyspark:

```
df_ge = ge.dataset.SparkDFDataset(df)
```

now you can run your expectation

```
df_ge.expect_column_to_exist("my_column")
```

> **Note** that the great_expectations SparkDFDataset does not inherit the functions from the pyspark DataFrame. You can access the original pyspark DataFrame by `df_ge.spark_df`

Answer (score 0):

See also the Great Expectations documentation/tutorial for an alternative version on converting a Pandas DF using `ge.from_pandas`: https://docs.greatexpectations.io/en/latest/guides/tutorials/explore_expectations_in_a_notebook.html